# Can we use same @HandlerChain for all my webServies which there are in different package name?

Tags: java, web-services, javax.comm

i have couple of webservice with different package location

what i want is to use same HandlerChain for all the webservice but
maven build is failing with
[Could not parse handler chain file] could not find file ....

as its locking for handler in same path where the webservice file is

but i want to use 1 location for all 
its possible?

@javax.jws.HandlerChain(file = "../../../../handler.xml")

public class GetOrderDataJWS extends com.amdocs.aif.provider.jaxws.AifJws {

```
@Resource
```

Answer (score 2):

It should work if you have it declared fully qualified:

```
package me.webservices.one
@WebService(...)
@HandlerChain(/me/util/security/handlers.xml)
public...

package me.webservices.two
@WebService(...)
@HandlerChain(/me/util/security/handlers.xml)
public...
```

When using maven you would place your handlers.xml file (or whatever you call it) under `src/main/resources/me/util/security/`

Comment: Even if you don't need to share across packages, this was the only way I could get the `@HandlerChain` annotation to pick up the config file correctly on Wildfly.